# power and modulo on the fly for big numbers

Tags: scala, modulo

I raise some basis b to the power p and take the modulo m of that.

Let's assume b=55170 or 55172 and m=3043839241 (which happens to be the square of 55171). The linux-calculator `bc` gives the results (we need this for control):

```
echo "p=5606;b=55171;m=b*b;((b-1)^p)%m;((b+1)^p)%m" | bc
2734550616
309288627
```

Now calculating 55170^5606 gives a somewhat large number, but since I have to do a modulooperation, I can circumvent the usage of BigInt, I thought, because of:

```
(a*b) % c == ((a%c) * (b%c))%c i.e.
(9*7) % 5 == ((9%5) * (7%5))%5 =>
63 % 5    == (4     *    2) %5 =>
3         == 8 % 5
```

... and a^d = a^(b+c) = a^b * a^c, therefore I can divide b+c by 2, which gives, for even or odd ds d/2 and d-(d/2), so for 8^5 I can calculate 8^2 * 8^3.

So my (defective) method, which always cut's off the divisor on the fly looks like that:

```
def powMod (b: Long, pot: Int, mod: Long) : Long = { 
      if (pot == 1) b % mod else {
          val pot2 = pot/2
          val pm1 = powMod (b, pot2, mod)             
          val pm2 = powMod (b, pot-pot2, mod)           
          (pm1 * pm2) % mod 
      } 
}
```

and feeded with some values,

```
powMod (55170, 5606, 3043839241L) 
res2: Long = 1885539617
powMod (55172, 5606, 3043839241L) 
res4: Long = 309288627
```

As we can see, the second result is exactly the same as the one above, but the first one looks quiet different. I'm doing a lot of such calculations, and they seem to be accurate as long as they stay in the range of Int, but I can't see any error. Using a BigInt works as well, but is way too slow:

```
def calc2 (n: Int, pri: Long) = {
    val p: BigInt = pri
    val p3 = p * p
    val p1 = (p-1).pow (n) % (p3)
    val p2 = (p+1).pow (n) % (p3)
    print ("p1: " + p1 + " p2: " + p2)
}

calc2 (5606, 55171) 
p1: 2734550616 p2: 309288627
```

(same result as with bc) Can somebody see the error in `powMod`?

Comment: I assume the `pot` instead of `pot2` when computing `pm1` was a typo? It should stack overflow otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer is here:

```
scala> math.sqrt(Long.MaxValue).toLong < 3043839241L
res9: Boolean = true
```

That means you can have a long overflow even for numbers which are less than that particular module value. Let's try to catch it:

```
scala> def powMod (b: Long, pot: Int, mod: Long) : Long = {
     |       if (pot == 1) b % mod else {
     |           val pot2 = pot/2
     |           val pm1 = powMod (b, pot2, mod)
     |           val pm2 = powMod (b, pot-pot2, mod)
     |           val partial = ((pm1 % mod) * (pm2 % mod)).ensuring(res =>
     |             res > pm1 % mod && res > pm2 % mod, "Long overflow multiplying "+pm1+" by "+pm2)
     |           partial % mod
     |       }
     | }
powMod: (b: Long,pot: Int,mod: Long)Long

scala> powMod (55170, 5606, 3043839241L)
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Long overflow multiplying 3042625480 by 3042625480
```

There you have it.

Comment: After the edit of the question, I was just about to comment about a possible overflow in the function when I came upon this answer. +1.

Comment: Tanks. Meanwhile I observed negative values in the debugger (but all my calculations resulted in the end positiv, which made it hard to guess an overflow), and that the method does the same thing in java, using longs. I guess I can detect overruns and use BigInt in these, hopefully rare, cases.

Answer (score 2):

Not familiar with Scala, but...

```
def powMod (b: Long, pot: Int, mod: Long) : Long = {  
      if (pot == 1) b % mod else { 
          val pot2 = pot/2 
          val pm1 = powMod (b, pot, mod)              
          val pm2 = powMod (b, pot-pot2, mod)            
          (pm1 * pm2) % mod  
      }  
}
```

Did you mean

```
          val pm1 = powMod (b, pot2, mod)
```

Notice the pot2 instead of pot.

Strangely, it seems that this should loop forever/overflow the stack, but who knows what Scala is doing.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right, I corrected my code accordingly. The error was made while I was trying to improve the variablenames, so the error occurs as described now, else it would loop endlessly, yielding in a stackoverflow, as you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Ok fellows, it took me some time, and finally destroyed a long but never proven assumption, which was, that if you multiply two 64-bit-positive integral values (aka: Longs, and practically only 63-bit, after all), you could overrun, and get negative values, but not get an overrun to reach positive (but wrong) values again.

So I had tried to put a guard into my code, to calculate my value with BigInt, it too big, but the guard was insufficient, because I tested for `res < 0`. `res < pm1 && res < pm2` isn't sufficient too.

To increase the speed I used a mutable.HashMap, and now the code looks like this:

```
val MVL : Long = Integer.MAX_VALUE
var modPow = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap [(Long, Int, Long), Long ] () 

def powMod (b: Long, pot: Int, mod: Long) : Long = { 
      if (pot == 1) b % mod else modPow.getOrElseUpdate ((b, pot, mod), {
    val pot2= pot/2
    val pm1 = powMod (b, pot2, mod)             
    val pm2 = powMod (b, pot-pot2, mod)
    val res = (pm1 * pm2) 
    // avoid Long-overrun
    if (pm1 < MVL && pm2 < MVL)
        res % mod else {
            val f1: BigInt = pm1
            val f2: BigInt = pm2
            val erg = (f1 * f2) % mod
            erg.longValue 
        }
      })
}
```

You might ask yourself, whether the Long-declared MVL is really needed, or whether a

```
if (pm1 < Integer.MAX_VALUE && ...
```

would have worked too. No. It wouldn't. :) Another trap to avoid. :)

Finally it is pretty fast and correct and I learned two lessons about overruns and MAX_VALUE - comparision.