# calculating modulo for large number

Tags: math, modulo

All,

How can I calculate 2^301 mod 77? I did check out the link [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177781/how-to-calculate-modulus-of-large-numbers). But did not understand the step wherein 625 mod 221 = 183 mod 221. How did the conversion take place?

Comment: I did not understand why express 625 as 183 + 2*221 ??

Comment: If I write it like `625 / 221 = 2, remainder 183`, do you understand? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder

Comment: By the way. Don't you do these kind of stuff in school in the US?

Comment: Erm... OK. I actually don't care. I was just a bit surprised that someone involved in IT doesn't understand the concept of _modulo_.

Comment: OK ..I don't really care either what you think. My question specifically states modulo for large numbers, not the concept. It might surprise you, but not many software engineers implement this on daily basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847069/power-and-modulo-on-the-fly-for-big-numbers) for an answer to your question.

Basically, `(X * Y) % Z == ((X % Z) * (Y % Z)) % Z`.

So, as a starting point, `2^301 % 77 == ((2^150 % 77) * (2^151 % 77)) % 77`. Keep splitting until you have reasonable numbers, then recombine. You will be able to keep your numbers at a reasonable size the whole way through.

Comment: Sorry I didn't think of this before, but if you are using Java there's `BigInteger.modPow()`. Then you don't even need to implement it yourself, (unless this was a homework assignment?).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the second part of your post, probably because you didn't include the link you actually followed. But your problem can be solved reading [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) page and implementing a proper algorithm of modular exponentiation